# QSplitter - When hiding an element contained in a splitter section, resize the section to fit only visible content

Tags: qt, c++11

When hiding an element in a section of a `QSplitter`, I'd like the section to resize and fit only the visible contents.

The following pictures demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

***Initial view:***

[image]

***After hiding element:*** (*Note*: the bottom splitter section does not resize )

[image]

***What I'd like to see after hiding the element:***

[image]

***MainWindow.h***

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

***MainWindow.cpp***

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    ui->widgetToHide->setVisible( ! ui->widgetToHide->isVisible() );

//    Something along these lines? This doesn't do anything.
//    ui->bottomContainer->resize( ui->header->size() );
}
```

***Main.cpp***

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

***MainWindow.ui***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>648</width>
    <height>514</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">color: black;
</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true"/>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: #535353;
</string>
      </property>
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="childrenCollapsible">
       <bool>false</bool>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="topContainer" native="true">
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: lightgray;</string>
       </property>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
        <property name="spacing">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="leftMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="topMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="rightMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="bottomMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <item>
         <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">background-color: lightyellow;
margin: 6;
padding: 6;
border: 1px solid black;</string>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>PushToHide</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="bottomContainer" native="true">
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">background-color: lightgray;</string>
       </property>
       <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
        <property name="spacing">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="leftMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="topMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="rightMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="bottomMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <item>
         <widget class="QWidget" name="header" native="true">
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>16777215</width>
            <height>100</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="layoutDirection">
           <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">background-color: lightyellow;
margin: 6;
border: 1px solid black;</string>
          </property>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
           <property name="spacing">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="leftMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="topMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="rightMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="bottomMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <item>
            <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
             <property name="orientation">
              <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
              <size>
               <width>40</width>
               <height>20</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </spacer>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">border-left: 0px; border-right: 0px;</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>Header</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
             <property name="orientation">
              <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
              <size>
               <width>40</width>
               <height>20</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </spacer>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QWidget" name="widgetToHide" native="true">
          <property name="styleSheet">
           <string notr="true">background-color: lightyellow;
margin: 6;
border: 1px solid black;</string>
          </property>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_4">
           <property name="spacing">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="leftMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="topMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="rightMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="bottomMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <item>
            <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_3">
             <property name="orientation">
              <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
              <size>
               <width>40</width>
               <height>20</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </spacer>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
             <property name="styleSheet">
              <string notr="true">border-left: 0px; border-right: 0px;</string>
             </property>
             <property name="text">
              <string>SectionToHide</string>
             </property>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_4">
             <property name="orientation">
              <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
              <size>
               <width>40</width>
               <height>20</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </spacer>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

***Split.pro***

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Split
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        MainWindow.cpp

HEADERS  += MainWindow.h

FORMS    += MainWindow.ui
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This did the trick.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    ui->widgetToHide->setVisible(not ui->widgetToHide->isVisible() );
    if (not ui->widgetToHide->isVisible()) {
        lastSizes = ui->splitter->sizes();
        ui->splitter->setSizes(QList<int> {ui->centralWidget->height(), 0});
    } else {
        ui->splitter->setSizes(lastSizes);
    }
}
```